# Which structure of project for GET request retrofit android I have to create?

Tags: android, get, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to create a simple application for getting a list of new messages from a server. I use `Retrofit` library for solving the following task. I have already read several sources of code, written some questions but I have some more difficulties. Firstly, I will show you the current structure of my request.

---

server request:

URL
https://my_server/v1/message/list

Method
GET

HTTP Header  - Authorization:Bearer $access_token

URL Params
type 
0 - for received messages
1 - for sent messages

```
Success Response
HTTP 200
{
    "count": int, # number of messages 
    "messages": [ # array of messages
        {
            "id": int, # message id
            "subject": str, # message subject
            "can_delete": int, # can it be deleted (1) or not (0)
            "new": int # message already read (0) or not (1)
            "date": str, # date of message in 'd.m.y'. If message was sent today format will be 'H:M'
            "receiver_name": str, # name of receiver if type=1
            "sender_name": str, # name of sender if type=0
        }, ...
    ],
    "next_url": URL,  # url for get next messages, if no more messages value is null
    "previous_url": URL # url for get previous messages, if no more messages value is null
}


Sample Call
curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://server/v1/message/list?type=TYPE
```

---

**interface code**

```
  @Headers({
            "Content-type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"})
    @GET("/v1/message/list?type=TYPE")
    Call<List<NewMessAnswer>> getInMess(@Query("id") Integer id,
                                        @Query("subject") String subject,
                                        @Query("can_delete") Integer can_delete,
                                        @Query("new") Integer new_m,
                                        @Query("date") String date,
                                        @Query("receiver_name") String receiver_name,
                                        @Query("sender_name") String sender_name,
                                        @Query("next_url") URL next_url,
                                        @Query("previous_url") URL previous_url);
```

---

**classes of request**

```
public class Message {
    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    String subject;
    @SerializedName("can_delete")
    int isCanDelete;
    @SerializedName("new")
    int isNew;
    @SerializedName("date")
    String date;
    @SerializedName("receiver_name")
    String receiverName;
    @SerializedName("sender_name")
    String senderName;
}
```

**Message Answer**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;


public class MessageAnswer {
    @SerializedName("count")
    int count;
    @SerializedName("messages")
    List<Message> messages;
    @SerializedName("next_url")
    URL nextUrl;
    @SerializedName("previous_url")
    URL previousUrl;
}
```

but I still don't know how to insert all the following fields into `listview`. After reading some tutorial I have created the following classes but I can't understand a way of sorting my fields into two classes and I'm also not sure in my interface for my request. Maybe somebody of you knows how I can solve the following problem.

Comment: put your message class in the Call<List<ClassName>>. this will reflect response in this type which you can simply use in adapter of listView/RecyclerView

Comment: thank you, but I can't understand how after it I can initialize the following interface at the mainactivity class, because when I then write Call<List<MessageAnswer>> listCall = mAPIService.getInMess(a,b,c); I have to initialise all variables which will require all fields in my interface. And I have to give them some value. Is it true?

Comment: these variables are the parameters required to call your api. Paste here the url and json response so that can understand better your problem

Comment: I can't give you any url and json responce because I can't do any GET request right now with the following code.

Comment: is these fields are required in api when you call the api... **id, subject, candelete, new_m** etc or these are in response?

Comment: I am not sure, I have to get the list of new messages, and I thought that I have to insert all these fields into interface)) maybe thay aren't required. I am only a beginner in android development.

Comment: this depends upon your api because if these fields are required then these fields you have to provided on the api calls ... otherwise these fields will come in form of response you are expecting. just make sure what your api need from you to provide result and what type of json you are getting

Comment: I have changed my question, maybe these detailes will clarify my task.

Comment: so as per your code says these classes you must have https://hastebin.com/beruhepuwo.http

Comment: use this ways .. you can change class name according to you.. because your url need only one param

Comment: and use access token in authorization section

Comment: i have post an solution .. you must go through that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Retrofit Interface**

```
 @Headers({"Content-type: application/json"})
@GET("/v1/message")
Call<MessageResponse> getInMess(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Query("type") Integer type);
```

**MessageResponse**

```
import java.util.List;
public class MessageResponse {
private Integer count;
private List<Message> messages = null;
private String next_url;
private String previous_url;

public Integer getCount() {
return count;
}
public void setCount(Integer count) {
 this.count = count;
 }


public List<Message> getMessages() {
 return messages;
}

public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
 this.messages = messages;
}

public String getNext_url() {
 return next_url;
}

public void setNext_url(String next_url) {
this.next_url = next_url;
}

public String getPrevious_url() {
 return previous_url;
}

public void setPrevious_url(String previous_url) {
 this.previous_url = previous_url;
}

}
```

**Message**

```
public class Message {

private Integer id;
private String subject;
private Integer can_delete;
private Integer _new;
private String date;
private String receiver_name;
private String sender_name;

public Integer getId() {
 return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
 this.id = id;
 }

public String getSubject() {
 return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
 this.subject = subject;
}


public Integer getCan_delete() {
 return can_delete;
}

public void setCan_delete(Integer can_delete) {
 this.can_delete = can_delete;
}

public Integer getNew() {
 return _new;
}

public void setNew(Integer _new) {
 this._new = _new;
}

public String getDate() {
 return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
 this.date = date;
}

public String getReceiver_name() {
 return receiver_name;
}

public void setReceiver_name(String receiver_name) {
 this.receiver_name = receiver_name;
}

public String getSender_name() {
 return sender_name;
}

public void setSender_name(String sender_name) {
 this.sender_name = sender_name;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, I can't still understand how I have to initialize the following interface at my mainactivity class, I found an advice to use something like that: mAPIService.getInMess(a).enqueue(new Callback<MessageAnswer>(){}. but I have to initialize the variable a.

Comment: yup. when you create Retrofit client then this interface will be used as a service in that client. and that will create this mAPIService like

Comment: mAPIService=retrofit.create(Interface.Class) will give you mAPIService

Comment: I am not sure whether your solution had helped me, because I got error connected with access token from my server

Comment: make sure you are entering the accesstoken

Comment: there are two ways to use accesstoken.. put directly in header section or use in retrofit client.

Comment: In my interface you can see my ACCESS_TOKEN, I am not sure, but maybe I have to copy the access token from my authorisation answer and insert into my header?

Comment: i have updated the answer .. now i have moved  access token param to the request.. try this ,, when you call this api add your access token and type.. hope this will work and if not i will show you the working example which i have done previously. but that will be bit lenghty

Comment: your answer is pretty cool, but as I understood I have to get access token from my previous success request, and then I have to insert it into header? maybe you can give me your example for better working?

Comment: the second approach is that you have to save that token in a variable in application class and the when you create retrofit client for calling you need to add add authorization and other headers in httpclient interceptor which holds the value from that saved variable so whenever you call that retrofit client you automatically invoke token and no need to add separately